# Choosing tags based upon thumbnails, update to Sqlite

Tags: python, html, image, user-interface

I have a [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database with 7000 rows with:

- Images / ID / Tag

  Images = array of urls of images (from the same "family")

  ID = Unique id so I can identify the images

  Tag = What are the images about (right now this is empty)

What's the easiest way to make a program so that the user can choose the tags (based on the images) to update the db?

Make a GUI??? (TKinter, wx, qt? )

Or do I need apache and php (I really would like to have to install apache and php)

Schematics of what I need (visualy):

```
Img1.1 Img1.2 Img1.3         BUT1  BUT2  BUT3

Img2.1 Img2.2 Img2.3         BUT1  BUT2  BUT3

Img3.1 Img3.2 Img3.3         BUT1  BUT2  BUT3

Img4.1 Img4.2 Img4.3         BUT1  BUT2  BUT3


<- PREVIOUS                            NEXT ->
```

And as you click the buttuns, it writes (appends) to a file something like: ID;TAG (the updating to sqlite, is the easy part, I think :) )

Ps. I don't know If I was clear enough, but the images (each row) have always the same tags.

How would you try and solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to use Django framework.

If you are already familiar with Python, it's very easy to create web based application like you want and manage sqlite database !
You should read django tutorial.

To create django model from your existing sqlite database, you could take a look at [this page](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/?from=olddocs)

Answer (score 0):

As to the tags input question, if you want your app to be web based, the most obvious route is probably the apache/php way (though that could be any other server/scripting language combination).

As to the design of your database table, I would try to normalise it. Read up on [relational database design.](http://www.google.de/search?q=relational+database+design)

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to do sqlite efficiently then you might want to look at SQLAlchemy. Its probably the best ORM database lib around.
http://www.sqlalchemy.org/